# ionic 3 Native Geocoder . can't able to find "thoroughfare","subThoroughfare"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3, ionic-native

**My code**

```
reverseGeoCoding(lat, lng) {
        this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(lat, lng).then(resp => {
            this.name = resp[0].thoroughfare + " ," + resp[0].locality + " ," + resp[0].subLocality + " ," + resp[0].administrativeArea + " ," + resp[0].countryName;
        })
    }
```

**My problem**

I'm having problems to retrieve `thoroughfare` from the reponsed data.

Comment: what problems you are having? question is unclear, did you debugged the script in chrome console? what response is coming in resp?

Comment: resp[0].thoroughfare or resp[0].subThoroughfare return null

Comment: locality,subLocality,administrativeArea, countryName  return proper values like       "Pune, india, 411013,"

Comment: what is value of thoroughfare and subThoroughfare?

Comment: Ref : https://github.com/sebastianbaar/cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder/issues/34